# No credentials plugin in the Jenkins sidebar container and impossible to update

Tags: docker, jenkins, credentials

I have some trouble with Credentials plugin in a fresh install of Jenkins inside a docker container.

First, I don't see it in the sidebar of the main menu but I can see it and administrate it via the plugins management.

Second, I have an error message in the update tab of the plugin management:

*SSH Credentials:
This version of the plugin exists but it is not being offered as an update. This is typically the case when plugin requirements, e.g. a recent version of Jenkins, are not satisfied.*

Impossible to update.

Just in case because it seems to be retated to my error, I have a second message:

*SSH Build Agents:
This version of the plugin exists but it is not being offered as an update. This is typically the case when plugin requirements, e.g. a recent version of Jenkins, are not satisfied.*

So in facts, I can connect a job to a public github repository but impossible tu use a ssh key with credential to do the same in a private repository...

Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Update Jenkins(currently 2.285), then plugins - that should solve all requirements issues.

Comment: THanks for your help. So, Jenkins is now updated in the container (I don't know why I didn't receive an update notification). The version is 2.285 and the jobs icons changed. Is-it normal if I don't see the Credentials icon in the sidebar menu? All plugins are now updated...

Comment: There was an issue with Credential plugins while ago [link to bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62725?attachmentOrder=asc) please check if you have most recent version of it :)

Comment: Yes, my plugin is up to date :) I'll create an new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in facts, the problem was due to different problem during the different updates process. After three update, everything is fine!